# Stretch text to fit certain width determined by coordinates over a plotted figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, coordinates, stretch

I have created a figure in python that has 2 sets of numbers, each as a list, plotted as text over the graph.

Figure here:

[image]

Code for plotting text.

```
ax.text(0.5, 0.965, plot_listmean, horizontalalignment='center',
    verticalalignment='baseline', fontsize=9.45, transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.text(0.5, 0.92, plot_listmax, horizontalalignment='center',
        verticalalignment='baseline', fontsize=9.45, transform=ax.transAxes)
```

I would like to stretch the text to fit across the entire graph. I am re-using the data to make different plots, so the amount of numbers in each list isn't the same across all figures, otherwise I'd work around it by increasing font size and etc.

I was wondering if it's possible to 'stretch to fit' the text between a set width is determined by certain coordinates (2 x coords), like you can sort of do with a microsoft office text box. I haven't had any luck with looking it up prior, so help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use a `ax.table()` and make it as wide as the axes

Comment: how do i go about doing that? I've messed around a bit with it and all I get is junk